# How to add parameters to flask-restful in python?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

How do I create an api call that does something like:

```
api.add_resource(MyResource, '/myresource/<myurlparameter>')
```

It is not clear how I can handle it from within:

```
class MyResource(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        print myurlparameter
        return ""
```

Also, I noticed I can only add_resource to one level:

```
api.add_resource(MyResource, '/myresource') # this works
api.add_resource(MyResource, '/myresource/test') # this this not work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find everything you need in the [docs](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

[Parameter in requests](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#resourceful-routing)

```
class TodoSimple(Resource):
    def get(self, todo_id):
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

    def put(self, todo_id):
        todos[todo_id] = request.form['data']
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/<string:todo_id>')
```

[Few endpoints](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#endpoints)

```
api.add_resource(HelloWorld,
    '/',
    '/hello')
```